# Lower SpamAssassin scores when certificate verification fails

Tags: email, ssl-certificate, spam, spamassassin

I’ve noticed that I’m getting junk mail from Norwegian companies that send from servers that Postfix says failed certificate verification. Is it possible to give these messages a lower spam score with SpamAssassin?

My mail is delivered locally by Dovecot through SpamAssassin:

```
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/spamc --headers -e /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
```

Comment: Rephrase your question. Higher or lower score? 2.5 or -2.5? And which rule gets triggered right now that you want to lower/increase?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you means the postfix "certificate verification failed" message which is logged due to an unsuccessful cert verification on a STARTTLS attempt.

As STARTTLS is most probably optional for an MX, there would be little value on scoring up stuff that failed the certificate verification, especially since this [could happen to perfectly valid servers as well](http://stevejenkins.com/blog/2011/06/fixing-postfix-certificate-verification-failed-for-gmail-untrusted-issuer-error-message/).

Anyway, if your mind is set to it, a feasible option would be to score on the base of headers which postfix would insert for correctly established TLS connections when [smtpd_tls_received_header](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_received_header) is set to "yes". Spammers are less likely to take the trouble to order an SSL certificate and set up their SMTP server to use TLS, but I would not score too much though - some of the spam is coming in through freemailers which typically would be TLS-enabled - you would build a freeway for this kind of spam with an overly high score advantage for TLS connections.